# Has Go changed much since its creation?

Tags: go

I've also been recently learning about Ember.js. It's not really an apples-to-apples comparison since Ember.js is a framework while Go is a language. Ember.js is relatively new and I've found out that some tutorials written as recently as this year are already out of date.

For example, is this blog from 2010, https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax, about Go's declaration syntax still valid?

Comment: Yes, that particular article is still valid. Do you mean has it changed much since its very first release, or since 1.0? The changes since 1.0 haven't been particularly drastic compared to the ones before 1.0. Go 1.x versions are backwards compatible to 1.0, and changes may be found [here.](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html)

Comment: @MikePrecup: versions that are more commonly found out in the world, so I'm guessing only versions 1.0 and later, and peterSO provided an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go hasn't changed much such its first public release. The blog is good.

Go has compatibility guarantees.

> [Go 1 and the Future of Go Programs](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat)
>
> Introduction
>   Expectations
>   Sub-repositories
>   Operating systems
>   Tools
>
> [Introduction](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat#introduction)
>
> The release of Go version 1 (March 2012), Go 1 for short, is a major milestone in
>   the development of the language. Go 1 is a stable platform for the
>   growth of programs and projects written in Go.
>
> Go 1 defines two things: first, the specification of the language; and
>   second, the specification of a set of core APIs, the "standard
>   packages" of the Go library. The Go 1 release includes their
>   implementation in the form of two compiler suites (gc and gccgo), and
>   the core libraries themselves.
>
> It is intended that programs written to the Go 1 specification will
>   continue to compile and run correctly, unchanged, over the lifetime of
>   that specification. At some indefinite point, a Go 2 specification may
>   arise, but until that time, Go programs that work today should
>   continue to work even as future "point" releases of Go 1 arise (Go
>   1.1, Go 1.2, etc.).
>
> Compatibility is at the source level. Binary compatibility for
>   compiled packages is not guaranteed between releases. After a point
>   release, Go source will need to be recompiled to link against the new
>   release.
>
> The APIs may grow, acquiring new packages and features, but not in a
>   way that breaks existing Go 1 code.